# Error al imprimir una estructura

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, struct

El programa tiene que leer y mostrar datos desde una estructura, 
el programa no tira error pero en la salida aparece el nombre después de basura (espacios sin asignar) y el apellido corrido cuando se muestra ¿Cómo se puede solucionar esto?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct {
    long int cedula;
    char nombre[15];
    char apellido[15];
    char telefono[8];
}Persona;

void cargar(Persona &per) {
    printf(" Ingresar la c%cdula: ",130);
    scanf("%ld",&per.cedula);
    printf("Ingresar el nombre: ");
    scanf("%s",&per.nombre[15]);
    printf("Ingresar el apellido: ");
    scanf("%s",&per.apellido[15]);
    printf("Ingrese el tel%cfono: ",130);
    scanf("%s",&per.telefono[8]);
}

void mostrar(Persona &per) {
    printf("\n\nLa cedula es: %ld\n",per.cedula);
    printf("El nombre es: %s\n",per.nombre);
    printf("El apellido es: %s\n",per.apellido);
    printf("El tel%cfono es: %s\n",130,per.telefono);
}

int darCedula(Persona per){
    return per.cedula;
}

int main() {
    Persona per;
    cargar(per);
    mostrar(per);
    darCedula(per);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es causado por las instrucciones del tipo:

```
scanf("%s",&per.nombre[15]);
```

En esa intrucción estas indicando que comiencen a guardar los datos desde la posición 15 del array.

Lo que debes hacer es usar `&per.nombre[0]`, o sencillamente `per.nombre` sin `&` ni `[]`.

Reemplaza tu función cargar con lo siguiente:

```
void cargar(Persona &per) {
    printf(" Ingresar la c%cdula: ",130);
    scanf("%ld",&per.cedula);
    printf("Ingresar el nombre: ");
    scanf("%s",per.nombre);
    printf("Ingresar el apellido: ");
    scanf("%s",per.apellido);
    printf("Ingrese el tel%cfono: ",130);
    scanf("%s",per.telefono);
}
```

---

Nota:

Cuando declaras un array: `algun_tipo algun_array[n]`, le estas indicando que cree `n` espacios de memoria de tipo `algun_tipo` contiguos:

```
|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|
 0   1  2  ....    n
```

Y para accedera la i-esima posición se usas el operador  `[]`: algun_array[i], por lo que es una variable, entonces al usar la instrucción `&algun_array[i]`, estas obteniendo la dirección de memoria del i-esimo termino. `scanf()` usa los argumentos secuandarios para guardar los datos, por lo que solo necesita su posición de memoria, y en tu caso le estas pasando la i-esima posicion dentro del array por lo que al final puedes estar escribiendo en memoria que no has separado(esto puede causar problemas). Lo mismo puede suceder con `printf()` ya que tambien puedes estar leyendo memoria no asignada, onteniendo basura.